# How to fix video rotation in Pitivi?

Tags: pitivi

How do you fix rotated video in Pitivi?

When I import video clips into my Pitivi project, they all show up in the correct orientation in the "Media Library" thumbnails, but when I drop them into a track, they'll often appear rotated 90 or 180 degrees, and there doesn't seem to any obvious way to change this.

If I view the video outside of Pitivi, say, in Totem or VLC, the video appears in the correct orientation. Why is Pitivi mangling my video clips, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I have no clue why Pitivi is not able to import then in the right direction but the Effect **Flipper**. You just focus a clip and select the right video direction (ex: GST_VIDEO_ORIENTATION_90L to rotate left).
Unfortunately, it doesn't seem Pitivi currently supports to apply a filter for multiple clips at once, I had to do that one by one.

(Note: I don't recommend to use effect Rotate because the input angle is not in degrees.)